# Is the span of S a subspace of R4?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 0 \\ 2\\ 2\end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

How would I go about answering this question? I tried seeing if its spans but it does not. Would I have to expand it to get a basis?

Comment: Those two are linearly independent, that is true. But notice that the dimension of a vector space tells you how many basis vectors you need to span it. $\mathbb{R}^4$ is 4 dimensional, so you only get a proper subspace. More precisely: the dimension tells you the minimal number of vectors spanning the space, and the maximal number of linearly independent elements in a set of vectors. (Assuming we are talking about finite dimensional spaces, like we are in this case)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't check if it spans $\mathbb{R}^4$, that is not the question.

- Note that $\operatorname{Span}(S) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$

$\operatorname{Span}\{S\}$ contains the zero vector, it is closed under addition and  scalar multiplication. It is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

To get a basis, check if $S$ is linearly independent, if it is then it is a basis of $\operatorname{Span}(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

The span of a set of vectors in a vector space is *always* a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(2,0,2,2)$ are linearly independent so they together can serve as a basis of a 2-dimensional subspace span$(S)$ of $\mathbb R^4$.